# OpenCL global array

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, opencl, global

I'm new to OpenCL and I've got a problem.
In my program I need an 2 dimensional array. I copied an 1 dimensional array to the graphic card. 
As I don't need the 1-dimensional array I've wrote a method which shoudl initialize all needes values. The 2 dimensional array should be __global --- I only have read operations on this array.

Here is my code

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
    unsigned char a;
} ColorRGBA;

__constant ColorRGBA array[4096];

__kernel void marchingCubes(__global unsigned char* output)
{
    // DO SOMETHING WITH array

}


__kernel void initValues(__global unsigned char* input){
    // FILL array MAKE 1-dimensional to 2-dimensional (4096,4)
    array = (ColorRGBA*) input;
}
```

When compiling the OpenCL Program, I get the following error:

```
:28:8: error: array type 'ColorRGBA __attribute__((address_space(2))) [4096]' is not assignable
        array = (ColorRGBA*) input;
```

How can I have access to the reshaped array in every thread?

Thanks 
Glethien

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the cast you have, but you cannot assign a pointer to an entire array.  You should do this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < size_of_input; ++x)
  {
    array[x].r = input[x];
    array[x].g = input[x];
    array[x].b = input[x];
    array[x].a = input[x];
  }
```

You will need to pass in the size of the input array of your function.

this assumes that your input pixels are in that order throughout the entire array.  RGBARGBARGBA, etc.

Comment: input is an array of length: 16384 unsigned chars.
I want to convert this into an array of shape (4096,4) and store it in  a global array. 

If i use your way, wouldn't it create an array with shape(0,x,y)?

Comment: @glethien I've made some edits to my answer, let me know if that is what you're looking for?

Comment: not really.... In python I do it this way:

        self.grid = numpy.load("./testData.npy")
        self.grid = self.grid.reshape((4096,4))

In the original input each block of 4 is one ColorRGBA

Comment: @glethen, you can't do that, because it's strongly typed, where Python doesn't care so much about types. This is the only way I know of to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would not bother explicitly recording your data - just deal with it as a 1D buffer.  You can pass the `row_width` as a kernel argument, and then calculate the appropriate index with `index = y * row_width + x`.

Comment: I solved it in a dirty way but it will work for me. As I am new to stackOverflow I cant post an answer to my question...

Comment: Well, keep participating and revisit this question once you have the ability to self-answer.  Glad you found a solution.